# How to write a script that outputs a table with two corresponding variables?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to extract information from a file to create a table with two variables at the end, so information from one column will correspond to another.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Extracting Name (2nd column)
name=`awk '{print $9}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt | grep -oP ";\KName=[^;]+" | 
uniq`

# Extracting values for 1st column
for pmz in `awk '{print $9}' PMZ_genes.gff3.txt | cut -c4-14 | uniq`
do
        echo "Symbols $pmz correspond to $name"
done
```

This is what I expect

```
Symbols PMZ0001 correspond to Name=One
Symbols PMZ0002 correspond to Name=Two
Symbols PMZ0003 correspond to Name=Three
```

This is what I have now

```
Symbols PMZ0001 correspond to Name=One
Name=Two
Name=Three

Symbols PMZ0002 correspond to Name=One
Name=Two
Name=Three
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your question in CODE TAGS and let us know. I am pretty sure you will get more elegant solution here.

Comment: @Mark : You set the variable `name` initially to a single string and never change it afterwards. Your loop is obviously executed twice in your example, and in every iteration, you output the (same) value stored in `name`. This explains the result you get. Also, we can see that `pmz` never takes the value _PMZ0003_ (unless you have forgotten to post this part of the output), so it's probably not output by `cut ... | uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

If rows have the same amount of item, you can use `paste` command to join them.

```sh
# name.txt
a
b
c
```

```sh
# id.txt
1
2
3
```

```sh
$ paste id name
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

You can also use output as file for `paste` command.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
lsr=$(ls -lasht)
owner=$(echo "$lsr" | awk '{print "owner:" $4}')
fn=$(echo "$lsr" | awk '{print "filename:" $10}')
paste <(echo "$owner") <(echo "$fn")
```